# New to OpenGL Shading Language

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm learning OpenGL recently and I want to work with GLSL in my codes.

I want to know where should I write the codes?

Is there an IDE or something?

Or should I write them some where in my source code?

what should I do for writing a simple shading program?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write GLSL code to anywhere you want. Just open a text file and write the code in there. Than you are gonna load the file and compile it from your source code. Alternatively you can embed the shader source into the source code with raw string literals if your language supports them.

You can find a basic example for writing and compiling in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4w7lNF8dnYw&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP&index=5). Programming language you use doesn't matter for compiling since it's done in OpenGL.